Eigensystem with a desired parametrisation
In equation (11) of this article the following matrix is given
H = {{r + t*Cos[\[Phi]] - I*s*Sin[\[Phi]], I*s*Cos[\[Phi]] + 
      t*Sin[\[Phi]]}, {I*s*Cos[\[Phi]] + t*Sin[\[Phi]], 
     r - t*Cos[\[Phi]] + I*s*Sin[\[Phi]]}}; 

\and its eigenvectors, in equation (14), are expressed in terms of parameter $\alpha = sin^{-1}(s/t)$. I understand that Mathematica would just given the eigenvector in terms of the given parameters as below
{{-(((-I)*Sqrt[-s^2 + t^2] + I*t*Cos[\[Phi]] + s*Sin[\[Phi]])/
     (s*Cos[\[Phi]] - I*t*Sin[\[Phi]])), 1}, 
  {-((I*Sqrt[-s^2 + t^2] + I*t*Cos[\[Phi]] + s*Sin[\[Phi]])/
     (s*Cos[\[Phi]] - I*t*Sin[\[Phi]])), 1}}

How can I obtain the answer in terms of parameter $\alpha$ just like equation (14)?

Try with assumption t>0 which gives an expression in \[Alpha], \[Phi]
{{-(((-I)*Sqrt[-s^2 + t^2] + I*t*Cos[\[Phi]] + 
         s*Sin[\[Phi]])/(s*Cos[\[Phi]] - I*t*Sin[\[Phi]])), 
    1}, {-((I*Sqrt[-s^2 + t^2] + I*t*Cos[\[Phi]] + 
         s*Sin[\[Phi]])/(s*Cos[\[Phi]] - I*t*Sin[\[Phi]])), 1}} /. 
  s -> ArcSin[\[Alpha]] t // Simplify[#, t > 0] & 


